# In the following scenario am I the server or the client?

Tags: c, networking, serial-port, udp

So I have a PC connected to a micro-controller via a serial cable and an Ethernet cable. Initially the PC sends a byte across the serial cable to the micro-controller. This results in the micro-controller sending back a UDP datagram via the Ethernet cable.

I want to know whether the code running on my PC should be a server or a client?

Comment: Seems more like a master in a master/slave configuration.

Comment: @sawdust To clarify, I meant would the code running on my pc which receives data by ethernet be a udp server or udp client

Comment: Client is per definitionem the initiator of a communication, so your PC is the client in this case. Nevertheless, you have to listen for UDP packets on the PC of course, when you await packets. This has nothing to do with the server or client role.

Comment: @Ctx except the "initiation" is done not by UDP. The PC has to bind to a port and listen for UDP packets, so I would say it is the server in this case.

Comment: @JeremyP UDP communication does not follow the client/server model, as opposed to tcp. You can bind to a specific port to listen for packets or you can send packets to a host, but the communication partners are peers in general, and the client/server considerations have to be done at a higher level.

Comment: @Ctx The client server model is an abstraction. TCP and UDP are protocols for talking between peers. Either protocol may be used to implement a client-server model. For example, a DNS server can operate using UDP. Whether the PC is a server or not depends on how you look at it. In terms of the  whole application, it is a client. If you focus only on the UDP part, it is a server.

Comment: Since UDP is a connection-less protocol, technically there is no client and server for raw UDP. If it were TCP, the side that initiates the connection could be called a client and the side that accepts the connection, a server. Of course, even for UDP, based on what kind of protocol you define on top of UDP, you can designate one side as a server and the other as client. In your case, there doesn't seem to be enough information about the protocol you are using to clearly define a client or server.

Comment: @JeremyP Both peers need a port, but the microcontroller doesn't need to know in advance what port the PC is bound to, but the PC needs to know the MC's port to start things off. That makes the MC the server, if any.

Comment: @user207421 No. The PC initiates the connection over a *serial cable*. It does not need to know any UDP port on the microcontroller. It does however, need to listen for the MC's response on UDP which means it needs to bind to a port and listen. The MC does need to know the port to send to on the PC.

Comment: Why does it matter whether you're a server or a client?

Comment: @user253751 Because my code does not work and I wanted to know if this is the issue

Comment: Client/server is an application concept. The _server_ is what provides a _service_, hence the name _server_. There are also peer to peer applications in which neither side is a server. TCP and UDP are transport protocols that do not have the client/server concept because they are below the application layer. TCP creates peer connections, and UDP is connectionless, and you can think of them as wires or pipes that transport the data, but have no idea about clients or servers.

Comment: @Ctx, "_Client is per definitionem the initiator of a communication_" That is really not true. A _server_ provides a _service_ to the client, and sometimes the server initiates the connection. We have servers that initiate connections to clients to periodically check on things and provide updates to the clients.

Comment: @th33lf "_If it were TCP, the side that initiates the connection could be called a client and the side that accepts the connection, a server._" That simply does not work in many cases. A _server_ provides a _service_. There are servers that initiate the the connections to clients, then provide the service to the clients. The RFC for TCP does not mention clients or servers because TCP is s peer-to-peer protocol. The RFC does mention a server (once), but it is an application using an application-layer protocol. "_...the "Telnet-Server" process is permanently assigned to a particular socket..._"

Comment: @RonMaupin This is a semantic definition on another layer, on the communication level a client initiates the communication. What you think about is a more abstract level where the borders between clients and servers can even blur in some cases.

Comment: @dilinex Where is the part of your code where you say whether your program is a client or a server?

Comment: @Ctx, Neither the TCP nor UDP RFCs (the very definitions of those protocols) say anything about clients or servers. On the contrary, the TCP process on each end of a connection is a peer of the other end of the connection. Protocols below the application layer simply do not have the client/server concept, and I have seen where trying to force that concept on the network stack can lead to errors. It is a bad idea to mix the concepts of one layer in the network stack with a different layer.

Comment: @RonMaupin The RFCs have a consistent terminology and it is ok, that they do not use the terms "client" and "server", despite the fact, that there _are_ TCP server and client in this case. On communication level, the service of a TCP server is, to accept a connection from the client. That on another (higher) level the roles of server and client might even be the other way round is completely irrelevant for this.

Comment: @Ctx, no, TCP creates connections between equal peers. The connection is like a pipe, and the pipe knows nothing about clients or servers, it only knows that when something goes in one end, it comes out the other end. Each end can send something to the other end, and each end can close the connection at any time. There is simply no distinction between the two ends, and trying to force a distinction will cause you to make mistakes by overlooking the fact that the ends are equal peers.

Comment: @RonMaupin A TCP server cannot connect to a TCP client, so much for "equal peers". Let's leave it here, you childishly insist that my terminology is wrong and I disagree with it. Continuing this fruitless discussion will do no good, but I will leave you the last word.

Comment: @Ctx you miss my point altogether; there are no TCP clients or servers. We have servers that use TCP to connect to clients to check for security problems, push updates, etc. You would certainly call them servers because they provide services to all the clients, but the servers initiate the TCP connections to the clients, so you would call them clients, not servers, and that is simply wrong. Trying to force application-layer concepts on the transport protocol does not work.

Comment: @RonMaupin I won't discuss any further, but I will show you this from "Unix Network Programming", which is quite a reference: https://flylib.com/books/en/3.225.1.61/1/ . Similar terminology is used in many other places. Just for you to reconsider your deadlocked opinion.

Comment: @Ctx, OK, that's fine, but it is that type of misguided thinking that has led to giant security holes in network applications. Remind me to never hire you for anything like that. We have had programmers who could not wrap their heads around the idea that servers could initiate the connections, and they are gone because out security servers must initiate the connections with the clients because compromised clients may not initiate the connection, and if a client refuses the connection, it is blocked from the network and wiped.

Answer (score 0):

Per Wikiepdia Client/Server:

> The server component provides a function or service to one or many
>   clients, which initiate requests for such services

And Master/Slave:

> Master/slave is a model of asymmetric communication or control where
>   one device or process controls one or more other devices or processes
>   and serves as their communication hub

The above scenario looks like the **Master/Slave**. In the initial, 'idle' case, there is no "SERVER" that is waiting ("listening") for requests. Only when the PC activate the micro-controller they will start communication (via UDP).

Answer (score 0):

You could use either term depending on what you were talking about.  As other people have noted, client and server are terms used to describe how distinct parties are involved in a service.  The terms can be useful in some situations (e.g. a web server and the browser as a client) but in other situations it's a less useful term (e.g. peer-to-peer protocols).

Presumably you're on stackoverflow because you're dealing with code. 
 In this case it's useful to be more precise and I'd suggest using terms to match whatever primitives are exposed by your language.  Most will use/expose [Posix sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) as their standard API, and hence you'd want to talk about/use `connect` or `accept` (potentially after `bind`ing first).  Note that these calls work across TCP and UDP (except `accept`), but the semantics of `send`ing and `recv`ing on the resulting connected sockets will obviously be different.